# st_table, st_data_t

Tags: c, ruby

**This is regarding RUBY source code. The structures st_* are in** **[st.c](https://raw.github.com/ruby/ruby/9060e87fa88155a203b69aeb2f05319b20796465/st.c)**

I have a structure

```
typedef struct TrieNode {
VALUE loadpath;
int expired;
st_table* dirs;
st_table* fileToAbsPath;
}TrieNode;
```

I need to be able to store and retrieve it using **st_table**, my key is a **char*** and my value is **TrieNode***.

To store it I have used the following line where child is of the type **TrieNode***,

```
//root->dirst is st_table*, child is TrieNode*, dirName is char*
st_add_direct(root->dirs, (st_data_t)dirName, (st_data_t)child);
```

To retrieve it I was planning on using

```
st_data_t buff;
//root->fileToAbsPath is st_table*, fname is char*
st_lookup(root->fileToAbsPath, (st_data_t)fname, &buff);
```

I don't know how to convert `buff` to `TrieNode*`.

Comment: There isn't enough information here for the question to be answerable.  Where is `st_table` and `st_data_t` defined?  What does `st_add_direct()` do?  Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Simply cast it. That is,

```
TrieNode *buff = 0;
st_lookup(root->fileToAbsPath, (st_data_t)fname, (st_data_t*)&buff);
```